# How do I combine Cloud Firestore and RXJava2 in a MVVM pattern

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java2

I want to load all my `BasicItems` in my Cloud Firestore collection.
And return it as an Observable.

In my `ItemRepository` I have the following function.

```
fun getAllBasicItemsFromFireBase(): Observable<QuerySnapshot> {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val myCollection = db.collection("BasicItem").get()

    return Observable.just(myCollection.result)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            it
        }
}
```

For me it is important to do this task in a background thread with the `Schedulers.io` statement.

How can I recognize that i got all the documents of my collection?
How do I combine Cloud Firetore and RXJava2 in a MVVM pattern?

Comment: What do you mean through "How can I recognize that i got all the documents of my collection"? You want to know when you got all documents within that collection in memory?

Comment: @ Alex Mamo I dont know if it is neccessary to regognize if it is completed. 
I want to read a collection of BasicItems and print it out on the UI.

Comment: Why to use RxJava when you can simply add a complete listener to your get call. Once the onComplete is triggered, it means that you already got all the documents within that collection.

Comment: @ Alex Mamo Oh man, thats the point. Thought I had to use the successListener. Thank you very much!